# pull mysql data for the last 60 minutes

Tags: mysql, sql, date, time

Hi I have have a column in my mysql db table called FirstAdded -- the date and is stored in this format:2013-03-04 16:37:05

I would like to pull all the rows added to the database in the past hour based on the FirstAdded column.

I've read around about INTERVAL but don't really know here to start

Can someone please help?

Thanks very much,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should get you started

```
SELECT *
FROM Tablename
WHERE FirstAdded > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
```

Comment: alternatively `WHERE FirstAdded > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR`. the outcome is identical, more a matter of personal choice